# Objective-C - How to concatenate /add text to a label

Tags: objective-c

I have label control on a storyboard.  (maybe should use a text control)?

```
self.labelMsg = "Begin.."
```

I'm running a process with 5 steps. How do I add the output to the label 
(another string message) to show the status of the process?

So the label text looks like:

```
"Begin..
Step 1 Complete...
Step 2 Complete...
Step 3 Complete...
Step 4 Complete...
Step 5 Complete...
Done !!! You Rock!"
```

How do you concat / add to an existing string - in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringByAppendingString`:

```
self.labelMsg = @"Begin...";

// After step 1 completes
self.labelMsg = [self.labelMsg stringByAppendingString: @"\nStep 1 Complete..."];

// After step 2 completes
self.labelMsg = [self.labelMsg stringByAppendingString: @"\nStep 2 Complete..."]

// etc...
```